# How Do I Use the <select onChange> Element to Change Content of a Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering if anyone has had any experience using the the following HTML element?

```
<select onChange="function()"></select>
```

I'm looking to add some functionality to a sports fixture page on a site I am currently building. I want the user to be able to select a round and within the containing area content appears depending on which round is selected from the option element.

I have an example of what I am exactly trying to [achieve here](http://www.afl.com.au/fixture). I have also had a look at the [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange) example. However due to my beginner level of knowledge and experience using JavaScript I am having some difficulties achieving what I'm looking for.

I have been searching solidly online and through the code of the AFL Fixture page but I just can't seem to find anything on how this can be achieved.

Any advice on how I can get this done would be greatly appreciated.

Thanking you in advance

Stu : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any restrictions on any libraries you can use?
Using jQuery you can do it quite simply by using

```
$('select').change(function(){ /* CODE HERE */ });
```

Check out this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pavkr/0k3ngfek/

EDIT:
Updated fiddle with dataset: http://jsfiddle.net/pavkr/0k3ngfek/1/

Comment: I have no restrictions on the libraries I use, I just use whatever I can to get the job done. This is what I'm after but I'm a bit confused how I can get the teams that will be playing into each round. This sort of thing is well out of my comfort zone. : )

Comment: @StuartCowley, Ok checkout the updated version here: http://jsfiddle.net/pavkr/0k3ngfek/1/ it includes a variable which contains a dataset, now the best way to get it would be do an AJAX call to a database but thats up to you.

Comment: Hey thePav, that's perfect mate! Thanks so much for that, I've been stressing to the max over that one. Cheers again! I would love to upvote this but I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

What you wanna use is [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

When `onChange()` is called, get the selected value from the function, and get the relative HTML content using `$.ajax`.

Then after the ajax call is completed, update the content using `jqXHR.done()` method.